# old school class initiation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm going through the Big Nerd Ranch iOS programming guide and the one of tutorials is telling you how to make an app that simply prints the devices location to the console. I have followed their code exactly and yet I am still getting an error when I run the app. The book that I am using is the previous year's edition so I'm guessing the error has something to do with changes to xcode or something of that sort. The book tells me to write methods for initiating objects in a werid way and I also think it might have something to do with it. Any thoughts on why this simple app doesn't work would be greatly appreciated. Below is my viewcontroller.m and viewcontroller.h files and the error that is printed to console when I run.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface WhereamiViewController : UIViewController
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@end
```

---

```
#import "WhereamiViewController.h"

@implementation WhereamiViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        //Create location manager object
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        [locationManager setDelegate:self];

        //Make location as accurate as possible
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

        //Look for location immediately
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"New Location: %@", newLocation);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Could not find location: %@", error);
}

@end
```

---

```
2014-08-16 13:25:22.295 Whereami[2832:60b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x9650af0 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/GeoServices.axbundle> (not loaded)
2014-08-16 13:25:22.298 Whereami[2832:60b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x9255180 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
```

Comment: The code looks ok. That message looks like the build failed. Are there other messages in the build log?  Did you add the core location framework to your project?

Comment: No, there aren't any other messages :/ I added add the CoreLocation.framework but do you think I need others?

Answer (score 1):

When this happens while building for the simulator your should `Reset Content and Settings` and then rebuild.

Comment: Oh ok. Where do I find that option?

Comment: Using the 'Help' menu you can search all menu options. Search for 'reset'.

Comment: Thanks! It worked and the error is gone now! The console log still isn't displaying the location which is weird but at least it's progress :D